# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Stellar's [1st moderator election](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the sole candidate:

[image: Glorfindel]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly - please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Thank you - I just want to reiterate what I said in my nomination: I'll do my best with the knowledge I have, but a subject matter expert would be a great addition to the team. If not now, definitely in the future, and we'll help them with what we know about Stack Exchange and the moderator tools.